# How javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet works over HTTP?

Tags: java, http, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.java do not have following methods like

```
doGet(), if the servlet supports HTTP GET requests
doPost(), for HTTP POST requests
doPut(), for HTTP PUT requests
doDelete(), for HTTP DELETE requests
```

Its only have service() method.

doGet()/doPost()/doPut()/doDelete() methods are only specific to javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.java class

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.java  is extended to communicate over HTTP protocol for a j2ee web application.
while javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.java also used for j2ee web application communication over HTTP.

My question is how JSF application communicate over HTTP while javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.java do not have HTTP specific methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `HttpServlet#doXxx()` methods are just an abstraction. Not using them doesn't mean that the servlet doesn't use HTTP (moreover, if that were true, the servlet wouldn't be invoked in first place).

If the servlet overrides only `Servlet#service()` method, it just means that the servlet has a global catch-all point for all HTTP methods. It can if necessary at some point still determine the actual HTTP method being used via [`HttpServletRequest#getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod--). This approach saves the programmer from copypasting same code over all `doXxx()` methods.

If you read the [`FacesServlet` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/javax.faces-api/2.2/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.java#671), you'll find the below block wherein the HTTP method is determined (line numbers match JSF 2.2 API):

```
671    private boolean isHttpMethodValid(HttpServletRequest request) {
672        boolean result = false;
673        if (allowAllMethods) {
674            result = true;
675        } else {
676            String requestMethodString = request.getMethod();
677            HttpMethod requestMethod = null;
678            boolean isKnownHttpMethod;
679            try {
680                requestMethod = HttpMethod.valueOf(requestMethodString);
681                isKnownHttpMethod = true;
682            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
683                isKnownHttpMethod = false;
684            }
685            if (isKnownHttpMethod) {
686                result = allowedKnownHttpMethods.contains(requestMethod);
687            } else {
688                result = allowedUnknownHttpMethods.contains(requestMethodString);
689            }
690            
691        }
692
693        return result;
694    }
```

Basically, the actual HTTP method is for the `FacesServlet` only relevant in order to determine whether it's a supported method or not. If it is, then the servlet will continue its job of processing the HTTP request the same way regardless of the method used.

Comment: So basically Servlet respond to HTTP request only?

Comment: Only those registered as web servlets (via either `@WebServlet` on class or `<servlet>` in `web.xml`)